# JNI: Invoke JAVA method from C++, returned objects, References and GC

Tags: java, c++, object, reference, java-native-interface

What is the rule when a C++ program(!) invokes a java method that returns an object? Is there an outstanding reference to this object? 
Must I call "DeleteLocalRef" to make sure the object is GCd, or will it be GCd automatically? The reason this is not clear to me, is because in all the examples and official documentation stating that "DeleteLocalRef" is not necessary, it makes sense to me only when a native "C/C++" method is invokes from java. But if the calling thread is a C++ method calling java, how will the JVM know that the object can be GCd?

Along the same lines: If I want to cache the object, must I call "NewGlobalRef"?

Could not find any reference to this...

Thanks for any reference and/or clarification

Answer (score 2):

I think [j.holetzeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176756/j-holetzeck)'s answer leaves out the important part.

From the same [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp16789):

**Implementing Local References**

> To implement local references, the Java VM creates a registry for each transition of control ***from*** Java ***to*** a native method. A registry maps nonmovable local references to Java objects, and keeps the objects from being garbage collected. All Java objects passed to the native method (including those that are returned as the results of JNI function calls) are automatically added to the registry. The registry is deleted after the native method returns, allowing all of its entries to be garbage collected.

I'll explain my interpretation of this using my application as an example:

A high-level overview of the flow of my application:

1. Android Activity launches in Java.
2. Once per frame the Android Activity calls into C++ to run our app's update loop.
3. During this C++ update loop our C++ code makes an arbitrary number of calls into Java using JNI.

How I interpret the quoted documentation is that automatic garbage collection can and will only happen in step 2, when our C++ update loop returns back to the Java code that originally called it.

If your application starts execution in C++ then calls into Java, I don't think you'll ever have automatic local reference garbage collection unless you then call from Java into C++ again (call stack: `C++->Java->C++`), in which case any references you make in the that top-most C++ function will be GC'd when you return to Java (`C++->Java->C++` -> `C++->Java`).

Comment: Does this mean that all objects passed into JNI are `unmovable` until JNI returns?  Can I read directly from the memory bypassing JNI without the object moving from one instruction to another?

Comment: @JohnnyV I don't know enough to be certain, but the documentation does say `A registry maps nonmovable local references to Java objects`. As such it sounds like at the very least there will be *references* that are guaranteed to be un-moved until a the `registry` is removed (on a `transition of control` from C++ back to Java). I can't say whether the actual data itself will always stay in the same location (I'm unfamiliar with the details of Java's memory management scheme).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is explained in some detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp16785):

**Global and Local References**

> The JNI divides object references used by the native code into two categories: local and global references. Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until they are explicitly freed.
>
> Objects are passed to native methods as local references. **All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references. The JNI allows the programmer to create global references from local references.** JNI functions that expect Java objects accept both global and local references. A native method may return a local or global reference to the VM as its result.
>
> **In most cases, the programmer should rely on the VM to free all local references after the native method returns. However, there are times when the programmer should explicitly free a local reference. Consider, for example, the following situations:**
>
> - A native method accesses a large Java object, thereby creating a local reference to the Java object. The native method then performs additional computation before returning to the caller. The local reference to the large Java object will prevent the object from being garbage collected, even if the object is no longer used in the remainder of the computation.
> - A native method creates a large number of local references, although not all of them are used at the same time. Since the VM needs a certain amount of space to keep track of a local reference, creating too many local references may cause the system to run out of memory. For example, a native method loops through a large array of objects, retrieves the elements as local references, and operates on one element at each iteration. After each iteration, the programmer no longer needs the local reference to the array element.
>
> The JNI allows the programmer to manually delete local references at any point within a native method. To ensure that programmers can manually free local references, JNI functions are not allowed to create extra local references, except for references they return as the result.
>
> Local references are only valid in the thread in which they are created. The native code must not pass local references from one thread to another.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this, but this explanation seems to pertain to Native (C++) being invoked from java. It does not seem to relate to a C++ program invoking a java method that returns an object... In the case of C++ invoking java, there is no: "...after the native method returns"

Comment: So do you say your C++ programm hosts/creates the jvm?

Comment: In this case I am pretty sure that you should call `DeleteLocalRef` (if appropriate) as you have to control life cycle yourself.